# Puppeteer - Iterate table rows and check box for specific row

Tags: javascript, html-table, puppeteer, browser-automation, web-testing

I have a table where the first column is a check box for each row and I would like to check the box for the row which contains specific text in a particular column of said row.

**Example**

```
X | Dave | Smith
X | Bill | Jones

Iterate through all rows and then check the box in the first column if the row has "Jones" for the last name column (col 3)
```

There are some great examples on the site for scraping the data from a table and just outputting said data, but I am looking to actually iterate through each row and then perform an action on an element within a given cell based on the needed requirements.

**scrape example**

```
const result = await page.$$eval('#example-table tr', rows => {
  return Array.from(rows, row => {
    const columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
    return Array.from(columns, column => column.innerText);
  });
});

console.log(result[1][2]); // "C2"
```

The above example is great for just pulling back the data in a 2D array, but I am hoping to iterate through each row looking for specific text in a specific column, then performing a click action on the element in col 0 to check the box.

I am using Puppeteer and am fairly new with javascript, so any direction someone may be able to provide would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried many failed attempts at something like this.

```
const rows = await page.$$eval('table tbody tr', (rows) => {
    const cols = await page.$$eval('table tbody tr td', (cols) => {
        for (let i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
            for (let j=0; j<cols.length; j++) {
                // if row[i] col[2] == desired text
                // then check box in row[i] col[0]
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Not sure I need the 2nd for loop for cols (possibly better to have it vs. not?) as I know what column the text I am checking for will be in and know that the first col of the row is always the check box.

I am also getting hung up on how I interact (click, get text) on the element within the location of that table as the iterating is going on.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to iterate the tr's:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  // find the tr with Jones
  let tr = [...document.querySelectorAll('tr')].find(tr => tr.innerText.match(/Jones/))
  if(tr){
    // find the checkbox and click it
    let cb = tr.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]')
    if(cb) {
      cb.click()
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm after, but am now getting this error.  Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: _toConsumableArray is not defined at__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:19.  I am using Babel and transpiling to es5, so is this part of my issue?  Any assistance would be hugely appreciated.  Thank you again!

Comment: It sounds like it but I don't see why you would use babel here.